# Angular Material. to highlight a table row on mouse over

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

we are using Angular Material table for our app:

> https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

could you please to show how to highlight a row on mouse hover?

Answer (score 96):

Update: recent versions of Angular have changed the class name used in the original answer, but the solution remains the same - apply the `:hover` selector to the table row class with `background-color` set to the color of choice:

```
.mat-mdc-row:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Original answer:

---

Add some CSS with the `:hover` selector to the `mat-row` elements:

```
.mat-row:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhgvee?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css)

Comment: I mean something like this: (onmouseover) highlightedRow.indexOf(row) style.background = 'grey'

Comment: That is not the `Material` way - If you change the theme then all other Material hover over will change but not this particular one

Comment: This isn't changing the theme, this is an addition to the Material theme behavior. Can you specify what is "the Material way" of doing this?

Comment: user tr.mat-row:hover instead

Comment: !important is necessary for me

Comment: OMG, why people don't like simple way like this according to other comments in this thread? I feel people are afraid and they need to be under some framework to protect them.

Comment: @AmirAzizkhani it should be: ```.mat-mdc-table tr.mat-mdc-row:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this styling the component in your theme file:

```
 @mixin newName-theme($dark-theme)

    mat-table tbody tr:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #b4b4b433;
  }

 @include newName-theme($dark-theme);
```

you can find more examples [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

Comment: This is better because it allows you to easily set different hover colors for different themes you may use in the same project. But I had to use `tr.mat-row:hover`

Answer (score 7):

Angular 15 changed this slightly. I'm now using:

```
  tr.mat-mdc-row:hover {
      background-color: yellow;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

in my case .mat-row:hover didn't work, it was highlighting the whole table. this works for me:

```
  tr.mat-row:hover {
      background-color: yellow;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Angular material > 15 and also .css style file for components, this could be helpful

```
.mat-mdc-table .mdc-data-table__row:hover{
 background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.514) !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Stay synced** with Angular Material v16+ theming (light; dark; other) and use like so:

```
.mat-mdc-table {
    tr {
        &:not(.mat-mdc-header-row):hover {
            background-color: var(--mat-table-row-item-outline-color);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I applied Bootstrap 4 class `.table-hover` to Angular material table.

```
<table class="table-hover" mat-table>...</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me neither of those worked in Angular 15, had to set background color for `<table>` and then change it for `<mat-row>` and `<mat-header-row>` (it seems that it already has hover but in same background color):

```
.table {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.header-row {
  background-color: white;
}

.element-row {
  background-color: white;
}
```

and assign those classes to mentioned elements

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [B.Habibzadeh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76706345/6342665) post here

for me this was enough

```
.mat-mdc-row:hover {
  background-color: red !important
}
```

And when you use your own class for all rows, even this worked for me:

```
.myRowClass:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red !important
}
```

Hope this will help someone who has issues in new Angular version.